Robot not orienting as expected in simulation
I am using nav2 for navigation task. I have a map loaded in rviz2 and there is a script that takes care of sending goal points to the nav2 action server, one after the other after reading it from a text file. I verified that the script sends the goal in the map frame_id.
I wanted to know the position and orientation of a goal point from the map, so I used the Set Goal tool on rviz2 to publish a goal point on /goal_pose topic and echoed the value in the terminal and got the following:


Orientation after reaching goal position:

Then, I put the same values in the text file from where the script reads the values:

Now, when I run the simulation, it takes the right coordinates but not the orientation. It gets oriented in a different way.

To reference the simulation- I am following Isaac Sim Navigation Tutorials and sending goals using text file as mentioned here. You can take a look at the exact tutorial script that publishes goal points here.
I do not understand why this is happening. Any help here would be appreciated!
